# How to add Hyperlink to $errorMessage in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, contact-form-7, contact-form

I've found a code that prevent duplicate entries from contact form 7 plugin, I need to add hyperlink to the error message, but it's not working properly.

`

```
/* Custome Codes */
function is_already_submitted($formName, $fieldName, $fieldValue) {
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/CFDBFormIterator.php');
    $exp = new CFDBFormIterator();
    $atts = array();
    $atts['show'] = $fieldName;
    
    $atts['filter'] = "$fieldName=$fieldValue";
    $atts['unbuffered'] = 'true';
    $exp->export($formName, $atts);
    $found = false;
    while ($row = $exp->nextRow()) {
        $found = true;
    }
    return $found;
}
 
/**
 * @param $result WPCF7_Validation
 * @param $tag array
 * @return WPCF7_Validation
 */
function my_validate_email($result, $tag) {
    $formName = 'Register / Sign In'; // Change to name of the form containing this field
    $fieldName = 'Email'; // Change to your form's unique field name
    $errorMessage = 'Email has already been registered, Please <a href="https://example.com">Login</a>'; // Change to your error message
        $name = $tag['name'];
    if ($name == $fieldName) {
        if (is_already_submitted($formName, $fieldName, $_POST[$name])) {
            $result->invalidate($tag, $errorMessage);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
// use the next line if your field is a **required email** field on your form
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_email*', 'my_validate_email', 10, 2);
```

`
------x-------------
[Please GO through this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Cwdg.png)

> Email has already been registered, Please  [Login](https://example.com)

I need to add this message to my error. Is there any way through which I can do that?

I need to fix my issue regarding the implementation of hyperlinks to  `$errorMessage` in PHP.

Comment: It applies HTML encoding by default, to ensure that only text content will get output. So you'll need to hook into another filter, to undo that. https://thisbailiwick.com/allow-html-in-contact-form-7-error-messages/

Comment: @CBroe I've added that code on my function.php but issue isn't solved yet